# Placing BeautifulSoup data into a Pandas dataframe - coming up blank

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

**Goal:** I'd like to create a data frame after scraping data from a website and narrowing it down to the table of interest (I am looking to get average meat consumption per capita for all countries in the world)

**Problem:** I have the table of interest but I am having trouble placing it into a data frame. However, **everything I try ends up with a blank data frame**.

****Output:****

```
<table class="wikitable sortable">
<caption>Countries by meat consumption per capita
</caption>
<tbody><tr>
<th>Country</th>
<th>kg/person (2002)<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-9"><a href="#cite_note-9">[9]</a></sup><sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-11"><a href="#cite_note-11">[note 1]</a></sup></th>
<th>kg/person (2009)<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-FAO2013_10-1"><a href="#cite_note-FAO2013-10">[10]</a></sup></th>
<th>kg/person (2017)<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-12"><a href="#cite_note-12">[11]</a></sup>
</th></tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" class="thumbborder" data-file-height="700" data-file-width="980" decoding="async" height="15" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Flag_of_Albania.svg/21px-Flag_of_Albania.svg.png" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Flag_of_Albania.svg/32px-Flag_of_Albania.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Flag_of_Albania.svg/42px-Flag_of_Albania.svg.png 2x" width="21"/> </span><a href="/wiki/Albania" title="Albania">Albania</a></td>
<td>38.2</td>
<td></td>
<td>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" class="thumbborder" data-file-height="600" data-file-width="900" decoding="async" height="15" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Flag_of_Algeria.svg/23px-Flag_of_Algeria.svg.png" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Flag_of_Algeria.svg/35px-Flag_of_Algeria.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Flag_of_Algeria.svg/45px-Flag_of_Algeria.svg.png 2x" width="23"/> </span><a href="/wiki/Algeria" title="Algeria">Algeria</a></td>
<td>18.3</td>
<td>19.5</td>
<td>17.33
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" class="thumbborder" data-file-height="500" data-file-width="1000" decoding="async" height="12" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/87/Flag_of_American_Samoa.svg/23px-Flag_of_American_Samoa.svg.png" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/87/Flag_of_American_Samoa.svg/35px-Flag_of_American_Samoa.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/87/Flag_of_American_Samoa.svg/46px-Flag_of_American_Samoa.svg.png 2x" width="23"/> </span><a href="/wiki/American_Samoa" title="American Samoa">American Samoa</a></td>
<td>24.9</td>
<td>26.8</td>
<td>
</td></tr>
<tr>
```

I am looking to pull the following column titles for a chart on meat consumption per capita for all of the countries in the world: Country, kg/person (2002), kg/person (2009), kg/person (2017)

**My Code:**

```
A=[]
B=[]
C=[]

for row in table_meat1.findAll('tr'):
cells=row.findAll('td')
if len(cells)==3:
A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
B.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
C.append(cells[2].find(text=True))
```

Need help placing the data into a data frame!

Comment: Have you checked the terms of service for Wikipedia? Some websites do not allow web scraping.

Comment: There are some solutions to do it but it's not ethical, Why don't you use web Wikipedia API?

Comment: I understand your concern - however, I have not found anything against it. The web scraping activities have all been for online data science classes I'm taking. They have exercises where they ask us to web scrape from Wikipedia.

Comment: For these kind of assignments, I don't think there is any problem. but for publication, you should definitely check it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question would be:

Use Selenium with chrome driver, to do so you can use :

```
pip install selenium
```

Then download the appropriate chrome driver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home) considering the os I checked version 86.0.4240.22 it worked fine.

unzip and put it somewhere like: `/Users/admin/software/chromedriver`

Then run this code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Metagenics-Ultra-Potent-C-1000-Count/dp/B004GLEUHI/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?crid=11YWA9XFVALBP&dchild=1&keywords=metagenics&qid=1603050330&sprefix=metageni%2Caps%2C224&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUFRRDdMVU5GNDFKQ1QmZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTA1NTc3NzAxSFYxV0k5MlFGUUZTJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA2MzM0MzAyWDBDSjNCNlFGRVJNJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ=='


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/admin/software/chromedriver",chrome_options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get(URL)
content = driver.page_source;
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
price=soup.find('table', class_='wikitable sortable')
print(price)
```

But be aware that web scraping is forbidden on some websites and you have to use their provided web API.

Comment: Thank you and I should've been more clear - I have been able to web scrape but unable to put it into a data frame. When I try to put it in a data frame, I still end up with a empty data frame set.

Comment: Your code shows that you are not creating a df. do you mean you end up with an empty list?

Comment: I am trying to pull the data from the web scrape and create a data frame...I guess my code is bringing up an empty list. Do you know how I can pull the data and put it into an organized data frame? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you add your code to scrape this page? and then explain what exactly you want?

Comment: The "output" in the original post above is what I got from the web scrape. I would like to put that into a data frame. In the "output", there are 4 columns titled: "Country", "kg/person (2002)", "kg/person (2009)", and "kg/person (2017)". Those are the 4 column titles and after that all of the information is there. I just need a way to put it into a data frame table.